# CodeNameOne Google Maps

Tags: codenameone

I am getting an error when I run a google maps app on an android for codename one. When I run it on the emulator I am getting no error. When I run it on a phone I get.

an internal application error occurred java.lang RuntimeException: waited too long for browser bridge

I think the problem is that I need to add build hints. I can find where to add them but I am not sure what format they should be in. I am also not sure what to add. I think I found a post that said I needed to add
 android.xapplication=
android:value="YOUR KEY"/>
android.xpermissions=

But I am not sure what format that looks like in the build hint entry form

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You do need to add the `android.xapplication` build hint so that your API key is provided.  You don't need to add the `android.xpermissions` build hint.  It will automatically be added by the library when you build int.

The instructions for build hints are all in the [README for the GoogleMaps cn1lib](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps#configuration).

The format for the build hint would be Name: "android.xapplication".  Value: "`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY"/>`"  Use the IDE's UI to place the build hints.  Don't try to paste them directly into the properties file.