# java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited too long for browser bridge with googlemaps

Tags: java, google-maps, codenameone

This is a weird question, because the error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited too long for browser bridge" is annoying me only since yesterday, while before everything was working like a charm. It is weird because I haven't changed anything to the app (before it is working, and in a moment is not working anymore)!

This is the error:
[image]

I attach the image of the situation in cgt.java:135 if i put a breakpoint in the specific line [image].

It is weird also because now EVERY apps I have deployed with a MapConteiner and Googlemaps API is giving me the same problem (and they were working well, before).

I have read the forum in [CodeNameOne Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192913/codenameone-google-maps), and I have already added the build hints: [image]

Thanks in advance for any answer,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a regression in the current map JavaScript HTML fallback that tries to wait for the browser component on a map that wasn't loaded yet. You should file an issue on that.

As a workaround just invoke zoom after showing the parent form.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work, even if I invoke the zoom after showing the form: exactly the same error! What do you mean by "file an issue on that?"...

Comment: I guess the problem is outside codenameone and netbeans: in fact, the app is working well in my device. The big issue occurs only when I run or debug on my laptop. Could be a problem with my connection?

Comment: It's probably because the debugger is pausing the threads and thus triggering a timeout with the thread that communicates with the browser component

Comment: Beh, I don't know why but the problem now disappeared.... without a reason I can explain (TLS handshaking?) ... Now everything works well again. Thank's a lot for the answers anyway!!!